# Redraw google after user input

Tags: javascript, php, database, google-visualization

So I have a Google Motion chart that displays data over time. A PHP is calling to a database to get data for the chart, that data is store into a JS file, and then the html file draws the chart (using a js script).

I want there to be a user input:

```
Start (millions):<input class="option" type="text" id="start" name="start" value="<?php echo $start?>"></input> |  
End (millions): <input class="option" type="text" id="end" name="end" value="<?php echo $end?>"></input> |
```

where the user input will set the x values of the charts (which is in millions)

HTML and JS SCRIPT THAT DRAWS THE GRAPH:

```
 function dataLoaded(myData) {

  };

  google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['motionchart']});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
var control = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
 'controlType': 'ChartRangeFilter',

 'options': {
   // Filter by the date axis.
   'filterColumnIndex': 0,
   'ui': {
     'chartType': 'MotionChart',
     'chartOptions': {
       'chartArea': {'width': '90%'},
     },
   }
 },

   });

  function drawChart() {
      // alert("dataLoaded called");
  var chartData = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      chartData.addColumn('number', 'Moving Avg Volume');


      chartData.addRows(chartDataRows);

      var upOptions = {};
      upOptions['state'] = {"playDuration":15000,"orderedByY":false,"iconType":"VBAR","yAxisOption":"6","nonSelectedAlpha":0.4,"yZoomedDataMin":0,"showTrails":false,"yZoomedDataMax":2.2,"xAxisOption":"6","iconKeySettings":[],"duration":{"multiplier":1,"timeUnit":"D"},"xZoomedDataMin":0,"yLambda":1,"yZoomedIn":false,"uniColorForNonSelected":false,"xZoomedIn":false,"dimensions":{"iconDimensions":["dim0"]},"orderedByX":true,"sizeOption":"_UNISIZE","xZoomedDataMax":122,"xLambda":1,"colorOption":"4"};
      upOptions['width'] = 900;
      upOptions['height'] = 600;

      var upchart = new google.visualization.MotionChart(document.getElementById('who_up_chart'));
      upchart.draw(chartData, upOptions);

 var downOptions = {};
    downOptions['state'] = {"playDuration":15000,"orderedByY":false,"iconType":"VBAR","yAxisOption":"5","nonSelectedAlpha":0.4,"yZoomedDataMin":0,"showTrails":false,"yZoomedDataMax":24000,"xAxisOption":"5","iconKeySettings":[],"duration":{"multiplier":1,"timeUnit":"D"},"xZoomedDataMin":0,"yLambda":1,"yZoomedIn":false,"uniColorForNonSelected":false,"showXScalePicker":true,"xZoomedIn":false,"dimensions":{"iconDimensions":["dim0"]},"orderedByX":true,"showYMetricPicker":true,"sizeOption":"_UNISIZE","xZoomedDataMax":122,"xLambda":1,"colorOption":"4"};
  downOptions['width'] = 900;
  downOptions['height'] = 600;
      var downchart = new google.visualization.MotionChart(document.getElementById('who_down_chart'));
     downchart.draw(chartData, downOptions);

      document.getElementById('loading').innerHTML='';
  }
```

My X axis is from 0 to 100,000,000, and so if the user enters in 1,000,000 to 5,000,000 I want the chart to redraw and show only those points.

Comment: Why is this tagged highcharts?

Comment: @Mark It was one of the recommended tags by the system, my bad. Do you think you could help me with ^^^/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is a [DataView](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataView).  A DataView is like an interface for changing how you view the data in a DataTable without actually changing the data.

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
var options = {
    //set your options
}

//Load Your Data Here.

var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
view.setRows(view.getFilteredRows([{column: 0, minValue: minTime, maxValue: maxTime}]);
var chart = new google.visualization.MotionChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
chart.draw(view, options)
```

I also noticed that you declare a ChartRangeFilter control at the beginning.  To bind that to a chart the both need to be part of a google.visulization.[Dashboard](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls#dashboardobject).  I was unable to determine if a MotionChart is capable of binding with a control, but you could give it a try and find out.